# Is there any risk using extremely high Zindex in WPF XAML?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I wonder if there is a risk of resource or performance when using super high `ZIndex` in a XAML view?

For exemple, is there a difference between this:

```
<Grid>
    <Rectangle Name="BigBoss" Canvas.ZIndex="1000000"/>
    <Rectangle Name="LitleBoss" Canvas.ZIndex="1000"/>
    <Rectangle Name="normalGuy" Canvas.ZIndex="2"/>
</Grid>
```

and this:

```
<Grid>
    <Rectangle Name="BigBoss" Canvas.ZIndex="2"/>
    <Rectangle Name="LitleBoss" Canvas.ZIndex="1"/>
    <Rectangle Name="normalGuy" Canvas.ZIndex="0"/>
</Grid>
```

I am not aware of the mechanic used behind `ZIndex` and how it is used to render the view but I assume that if there is a loop iterating every elements of the 1000000 "used" `ZIndex`, there would be clearly a performance issue.

Comment: It looks like game dev and I'd discourage using wpf for game development purposes especially when you are talking about thousand of objects on screen simultaneously. Rendering is not going to be optimal compared to a open gl or directx drawing surface implementation

Comment: Thanks @Charleh but I'm not develloping a game. I'm on a desktop application using WPF, XAML and C#. I use a maximum of 10-15 items with a mannualy setted ZIndex.

Comment: But to more specifically answer your question; z index is used for sorting the drawn elements and likely will have similar performance no matter the values. It may be that many switches of z indexes between a lot of elements per drawing pass could affect performance because of the need to sort the objects constantly but this is speculation. In short if you want performance wpf isn't the tool for the job

Comment: In the case as you've stated with around 10 items I wouldnt worry about the z index. Use whatever values you want, it won't have any noticeable effect. My question would be , why the question about performance with such a small number of elements, is it just curiosity? Remember that a lot of sorting happens in the wpf drawing process anyway due to the way you can stack elements

Comment: Okay thanks @Charleh. Make that an answer with a little of explanation and a source if you're able to and I'll make this the approved answer.

Comment: Whenever I see a bunch of clutter with things like manually set ZIndex's and Tab Orders and the likes.....I make that person google DOM, just my two cents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are not any performance risk. The ZIndex is a property for setting the priority of an item inside a wpf `Panel` (the same panel). If you set ZIndex=10000 to an item, it doesn't means there will be 10000 layers. It means that if there are any other item, with ZIndez lower, in the same panel, that overlap the first item, then this other item will be renderer behind the first item.

By default the visual tree order has the same effect.